# windows ink keyboard not showing in textbox

Tags: windows, keyboard, ink, handwriting

device : Lenovo Yoga 6 with touchscreen and pen support.
windows version 21H1 (and problem persist in previously 20H2).
the hardware is working fine: touchscreen is normal, pen support is normal.

**Problem : windows ink keyboard (handwriting recognition to text) is not working on textbox for all application except the windows search. problem persist whether in desktop mode or in tablet mode.**

only one language installed : English-US.(windows display languange, preferred language with handwriting installed-the whole package), and this one language is used in windows display, apps, regional format, keyboard and speech, and administrative language settings.
OnScreenKeyboard can be activated, but it's not what i'm looking for.

some of the things already tried:

1. toggled on or off: settings-Devices-typing-"show the touch keyboard when not in tablet mode and there's no keyboard detected".
2. on the advanced keyboard settings: Override for default input method : English-US
3. touch keyboard button in the taskbar is active, but clicking it does not open anything
4. Settings-Pen & Windows Ink : "when I tap a text field with my pen, use handwriting to input text" -> tried "Only in tablet mode" and "when the keyboard isn't attached" both doesn't seems to show any difference
5. Setting-EaseOfAccess-Keyboard => use the on screenkeyboard show the on screen keyboard, but this in not what i want.
6. tried registry change : Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Pen with RegDword "EnableEmbeddedInkControl" =1
7. tried registry change : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Scaling with MonitorSize = 22.5
8. combination of above (and countless reboot in between), whether in physical laptop mode or physical tabled mode, or software tabled mode toggled on and off. (the tablet mode recognition is normal)
9. SFC /scannow, DISM /RestoreHealth ==> no problem here
10. all drivers are updated using lenovo vantage.
11. No error found on the device manager

Maybe related, but im not sure : in the windows notification bar, button for "screen snip" is not working, but the app can be accessed via start menu.

If anybody have any ideas, reply is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After Trying other dozen of fix from other forums nothing worked. (also tried tools like cc cleaner), but widening the search for problem with windows update (although that is not my problem), I give "windows repair" a try (https://www.majorgeeks.com/mg/getmirror/tweaking_com_windows_repair,1.html)

trying only the first type fix (Reset Registry Permission), it was able to return full functionality of the windows soft keyboard (and ink handwriting), it also fix the broken screen snip button i mentioned.

Well, I hope this post help other people with same problem. Cheers.